# errors while installing gulp-sass on linux manjaro

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, manjaro

When I try to install gulp-sass, I get a lot of errors. I recently switched to my linux machine from my windows machine, and on windows it worked perfectly fine. Now when I try to install gulp (`npm install gulp`) it works fine. But when I try to install gulp-sass (`npm install gulp-sass`) right after that, i get a ton of errors.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /home/pera/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/bin/node /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/pera/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.3.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:453:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:661:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.36-2-MANJARO
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/pera/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/bin/node" "/home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/pera/Desktop/Server/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pera/.npm/_logs/2021-06-04T21_00_45_303Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

```
python2 Error: not found: python2
```

node-gyp couldn't find python2 so it falls back to /usr/bin/python which will be python3.

Then:

```
import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

The 'print' syntax changed in python3, so this is no longer valid.

Install Python2 and you'll resolve this error.